# Lib GDX html running gives an error with System Java Compiler (Eclipse) (Windows 7)

Tags: java, html, libgdx

I am trying to compile a HTML project, from [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBsvuT7MzpY). But when I am running that HTML external tool, it gives me an error:

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:core:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:compileJava'.
> Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.297 secs
```

I was searching on internet, but I didn't find a solution which worked for me. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello sorry for my English, while I do not use windows, but I think you have to install the Java JDK, look for this if you do not have it, I think he had to do something like this:

1 Right-click the My Computer icon on your desktop and select Properties.

2 Click the Advanced tab.

3 Click the Environment Variables button.

4 Under System Variables, click New.

5 Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME.

;C:\Program Files\Java\YOUR VERSION JAVA JDK \src.zip

Answer (score 0):

It actually doesnt work. If i set the loc to : C:\Program Files\Java\jre7 It gives an error which i show in the first post.

If i set the loc to : C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

I tried to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\libs but the same.

BTW: I dont have JDK, i have only JRE.. I downloaded an JDK from java˘s web, installed it, and in my Java folder appeared only the JRE.